# 2 layer neural network in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am new to tensorflow and trying to train the following two layer network. It seems it is not working as cross entropy is not decreasing as iteration. I think I am screwed up connecting hidden layer to output layer. Please help me if you can see the problem,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np
import sys

x = loadmat('../mnist_data/ex4data1.mat')
X = x['X']

# one hot conversion
y_temp = x['y']
y_temp = np.reshape(y_temp, (len(y_temp),))
y = np.zeros((len(y_temp),10))
y[np.arange(len(y_temp)), y_temp-1] = 1.



input_size = 400
hidden1_size = 25
output_size = 10
num_iters = 50
reg_alpha = 0.05


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size], name='data')
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_size, input_size], tf.float32, name='weights_1st_layer'))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_size], tf.float32), name='bias_layer_1')
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size, hidden1_size], tf.float32, name='weights_2nd_layer'))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size], tf.float32), name='bias_layer_2')


hidden_op = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1, transpose_b=True), b1))
output_op = tf.matmul(hidden_op, W2, transpose_b=True) + b2
pred = tf.nn.softmax(output_op) 

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='actual_labels')


cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=y_, logits=output_op))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(reg_alpha).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(50):
    print ('training..', _)
    print (sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x : X, y_ : y}))

corr_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, axis=1), tf.argmax(y_, axis=1))
acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(corr_pred, tf.float32))
print (sess.run(acc, feed_dict={x:X, y_:y}))
sess.close()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with TF, but it looks like you're initializing all of the weights and biases to zero. Is that correct? If so, it's a huge problem, as it prevents breaking symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initialising your weights as randoms, not zeros.

So instead of:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_size, input_size], tf.float32, name='weights_1st_layer'))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size, hidden1_size], tf.float32, name='weights_2nd_layer'))
```

use:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden1_size, input_size], tf.float32, name='weights_1st_layer'), stddev=0.1))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([output_size, hidden1_size], tf.float32, name='weights_2nd_layer'), stddev=0.1))
```

Check [this](https://www.quora.com/If-one-initializes-a-set-of-weights-in-a-Neural-Network-to-zero-is-it-true-that-in-future-iterations-they-will-not-be-updated-by-gradient-descent-and-backpropagation) nice summary why initialising all the weights to zero prevents the network from training.

Comment: yes. that works. initially i was following an implementation of single layer network. weights were initialized to 0 in case of single layer. i think the prior layer before output can have 0 initialization, layers before that must have non zero initialization to let GD work...Thanks